# How to search for an image with JavaScript on Google image?

Tags: javascript, image, google-image-search

I want to start searching for an image, stored locally, using JavaScript and Google Image ([Google Image Link](https://images.google.com/)). I know how to do it manually, but I can't figure out how to automate the search through JavaScript. Is that possible? I can't find anything on the Internet and I don't know how to attack the problem.

Thank you for your help and/or your advice.

Ps: Here is an example of a URL obtained after the manual search of an image on Google Image
[Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisxr8J2wjm3cU3VprEBzJdEzLL8QDA5gu7jyC4H3qnzxeWzl9ns--hshs9jjNY_1QofGuQ_1gtBWOcHPJtsjRBZzACNvg8BeHdme8rDrOp7IrdLo5Vn9Vj2UPrfHKwb9ltmfhl76pFFsNGUShKXMoZmCgSHTZ8o2_1hQeWlb9io3Bz_1pl8db_1jsSMjZyEnQ5YpGXh5hEmtBJCDmRAGD0OaXOCbaWFAmCWpyYDha4HBZwE63IQRXGUbTkA_1Y7oHqi1wWAJqkLcpS1y4-H3Bo05HTDaAW1ABF1dQL6QnAdf8jmRHqL5ixgvxT4Z6Gp2uHfmWgz0UWqoU&btnG=Recherche%20par%20image&hl=fr-PT)

Comment: I believe this should point in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615926/use-javascript-to-get-a-random-image-from-google-images

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I now have a starting point: Google Custom Search with images. I'm going to investigate. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think Google Custom Search API doesn't support the feature i am looking for the moment. It allows me to search images using keyword, but it doesn't allow me to search images using an image file. This source seems to confirm what i suppose (https://support.google.com/customsearch/forum/AAAAg_SjYhUWhJnrHVD-mQ/?hl=en).

Comment: did you find any solution ?