# How to import API/external JS in a JS file?

Tags: javascript, web, firefox

I'm coding a web extension for Firefox and I would like to make the same thing as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32616807/10452863 , which means use Google API to search random images.

How can I import the Google API in my .js file ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to try out any npm package, I would suggest **[googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#google-apis)**. You can use all Google APIs with this node.js client library.

````
          To import use ``` const { google } = require("googleapis")```
````